# Jenkins Project Versioning

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I have a java project with version eg 2.0.1 now we have a major release change eg 3.0.0. what I want is to pass the version of project i want to build as parameter. How can this functionality be achived.

Answer (score 0):

You should define a global variable in Global config. You can find it `Manage Jenkins => Configure` and you can define global variables under `Global properties => Environment variables`. You will be able to use this environment variable in all or your jobs (Eg.: `echo "${MY_JAVA_PROJECT_VERISON}"`). You can see some different solution to define global variable on this site: https://medium.com/@mukeshsingal/access-jenkins-global-environment-variables-using-groovy-or-java-b5c1e6b53685

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that eg. by plugin [Parametrized build](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Parameterized+Build)

Then simply check `"This build is parametrized"` and define one-or-more parameters, afterwards on each build you will find `Parameters` in the left menu bar

[image]

In pipeline job you can access via `"${params.paramName}"`, `params.paramName`, etc. , should works also `evn.paramName`

These parameters can be passed also once you will choose to trigger the job remotely - by URL